Custom Syncfusion Grid in Blazor
I need to create a custom SfGrid, so I made a class CustomGrid that inherits SfGrid :
public class CustomGrid<T> : SfGrid<T>
{
...
}

How can I tap into GridEvents.OnActionBegin to execute some code ? I tried this but you can't assign a function to an EventCallback
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        GridEvents.OnActionBegin += ActionHandler;
    }
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}


public async Task ActionHandler(ActionEventArgs<T> Args)
{
    if (Args.RequestType == Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.Action.Sorting)
    {
        Console.WriteLinte("Sorting");
    }
}


I would use composition over inheritance here. It would also give you the freedom to change your grid provider down the path if required.

Can you clarify what you mean by composition ?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance for composition vs inheritance..   I may be wrong with SfGrid, but I don't think grids are designed to be inherited from.  They're complex objects and you are likely to run into access issues with internal and private methods and properties.
